# Python Inheritance, changing an initialized member of base class

Tags: python, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

If I have an inherited class like this:

```
phonebook = {"John": 123, "Rose": 234, "Miles": 345}
class Base(AbstractBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.phonebook = phonebook

    def doSomething(self):
        aFunctionThatDoesSomething(phonebook)
```

How can I inherit this class and call the function if I have a different phonebook I want to use? I know I can add it as a parameter, but is there a way to do it without adding it to **init**?

Ideally I want to write a function override that uses a new value that's initialized. So 
something like this:

```
class Derived(Base):
   def aFunctionThatDoesSomething(self):
       # I want to add some names to the phonebook in the base class here
       self.phonebook = addContacts(self.phonebook)
       super().aFunctionThatDoesSomething()
```

Comment: possibly making use of the AbstractBase `__init__` within the new `class Derived` and add `*args` within the constructor

Comment: Could you give me an example?